# Why does this QR-DQN network not learn?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I referred to https://github.com/senya-ashukha/quantile-regression-dqn-pytorch/blob/master/qr-dqn-solution-cool.ipynb

I have no problem solving CartPole problem when using the basic Linear network as follows:

```
    def __init__(self, int_states, int_actions, int_quants):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)

        self.int_quants = int_quants
        self.int_actions = int_actions

        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(int_states, 256)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(256, int_actions*int_quants)

    def forward(self, state):
        state = self.layer1(state)                                              
        state = torch.tanh(state)                                             
        state = self.layer2(state)                                             

        return state.view(-1, self.int_actions, self.int_quants)
```

Before applying it to Atari games, I tried solving the same CartPole problem with Conv2D networks. However, it doesn't learn anything this time.

I made a (2 channels, 1 row, 2 columns) array and set the 2nd channel of which as state:

```
>>> state

array([[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],
       [[ 0.22120677,  1.75521159, -0.26231307, -2.71662474]]])
```

I thought that the new network would be able to find out that the 1st channel is meaningless and, ultimately, it would work the same as the Linear network.

I'd like to know what I've missed or if there are errors.

The full Conv2d code that I tested:

````
import gym
import torch
import pickle
import random
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

import torch.nn.functional as F
from collections import deque

 
def huber(x, k=1.0):
    return torch.where(x.abs() < k, 0.5 * x.pow(2), k * (x.abs() - 0.5 * k))
 
 
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, int_states, int_actions, int_quants):
        nn.Module.__init__(self)
 
        self.int_quants = int_quants
        self.int_actions = int_actions
 
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 32, 1, stride=1) 
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 1, stride=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 1, stride=1)
        
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(256, 64)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(64, int_actions*int_quants)
 
    def forward(self, state):

        state = F.relu(self.conv1(state))
        state = F.relu(self.conv2(state))
        state = F.relu(self.conv3(state))
        state = torch.flatten(state, 1)
        
        state = self.layer1(state)                                             
        state = torch.tanh(state)                                              
        state = self.layer2(state)                                             
 
        return state.view(-1, self.int_actions, self.int_quants)               
 
    def selectAction(self, state, eps):
        if not isinstance(state, torch.Tensor):
            state = torch.Tensor([state])
 
        if random.random() > eps:
            action = self.forward(state).mean(2).max(1)[1]
 
        else:
            action = torch.randint(0, 2, (1,))
 
        return int(action)                                                   
 
 
class Agent():
    def __init__(self, int_deqSize, int_batchSize=32):
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=int_deqSize)
        self.int_batchSize = int_batchSize
 
        self.Zmain   = Network(int_states=int_states, int_actions=int_actions, int_quants=int_quants )
        self.Ztarget = Network(int_states=int_states, int_actions=int_actions, int_quants=int_quants )    
        self.Ztarget.load_state_dict(self.Zmain.state_dict())   
 
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.Zmain.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
 
    def push(self, state, action, stateN, reward, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, stateN, reward, done))
        self.replay()
 
    def sample(self):
        if len(self.memory) > self.int_batchSize:
            batch = random.sample(self.memory, self.int_batchSize)
 
            states, actions, statesN, rewards, dones = zip(*batch)
 
            states  = torch.Tensor(np.array(states))
            actions = torch.Tensor(np.array(actions))                    
            statesN = torch.Tensor(np.array(statesN))            
            rewards = torch.Tensor(np.array(rewards))         
            dones   = torch.Tensor(np.array([int(val) for val in dones]))
 
            return states, actions, statesN, rewards, dones
 
    def replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) > self.int_batchSize:
            states, actions, statesN, rewards, dones = self.sample()
 
            theta = self.Zmain(states)[np.arange(self.int_batchSize), actions.long()]   
 
            Znext = self.Ztarget(statesN).detach()
            Znext_max = Znext[np.arange(self.int_batchSize), Znext.mean(2).max(1)[1]]
 
            Ttheta = rewards.unsqueeze(1) + gamma * (1 - dones.unsqueeze(1)) * Znext_max
 
            self.Ttheta = Ttheta.unsqueeze(1)       
            self.theta = theta.unsqueeze(1) 
                
            diff = Ttheta.unsqueeze(1) - theta.unsqueeze(1)                    
            self.diff = diff                       
 
 
            loss = huber(diff) * (tau - (diff.detach() < 0).float()).abs()
            loss = loss.mean()
            self.loss = loss
 
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()
 
 
eps_start, eps_end, eps_dec = 0.9, 0.1, 500 
eps = lambda steps: eps_end + (eps_start - eps_end) * np.exp(-1. * steps / eps_dec)
 
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
int_states  = env.observation_space.shape[0]                                                   
int_actions = env.action_space.n                                                                
int_quants = 2

agent = Agent(int_deqSize=5000, int_batchSize=32)
 
steps_done = 0
running_reward = None
gamma, int_batchSize = 0.99, 32 
tau = torch.Tensor((2 * np.arange(agent.Zmain.int_quants) + 1) / (2.0 * agent.Zmain.int_quants)).view(1, -1)      
 
int_episodes = 301

state = np.zeros(8).reshape(2,1,4)
 
for episode in range(int_episodes):
    sum_reward = 0
    state[1] = env.reset()
    done = False
 
    while not done:
        steps_done += 1
 
        action = agent.Zmain.selectAction(torch.Tensor(state).unsqueeze(0), eps(steps_done))
 
        stateN, reward, done, info = env.step( action )
        
        state[1] = stateN
        stateN = state
        
        agent.push(state, action, stateN, reward, done)
        sum_reward += reward
 
        if steps_done % 100 == 0:
            agent.Ztarget.load_state_dict(agent.Zmain.state_dict())
 
    print( f"EPISODE {episode} REWARD {sum_reward}")
 
```
````